# Netcdf4 for Python successful save, failed to visualize

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am having a hard time when I want to add new groups on a existing netcdf file with python. MWE works on my machine.

MWE

```
import os 
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import netcdf
from netCDF4 import Dataset

try:
    os.remove('test.nc')
except OSError:
    pass

mydata = np.linspace(1,30,30)

g=Dataset('test.nc','w',format='NETCDF4') 
g.description = 'The data in this file was created for a test'
g.close()

#Do stuff

g=Dataset('test.nc','r+',format='NETCDF4') 
g1 = g.createGroup('grp1')
g1.createDimension('dim', len(mydata))
ncdata = g1.createVariable('data1', 'f8', ('dim',)); ncdata[:] = mydata
ncdata = g1.createVariable('data2', 'f8', ('dim',)); ncdata[:] = mydata
g.close()


#Do stuff

g=Dataset('test.nc','r+',format='NETCDF4') 
g1 = g.createGroup('grp2')
g1.createDimension('dim', len(mydata))
ncdata = g1.createVariable('data1', 'f8', ('dim',)); ncdata[:] = mydata
ncdata = g1.createVariable('data2', 'f8', ('dim',)); ncdata[:] = mydata
g.close()
```

However I can't open my file with `ncview`, instead I get that

> Ncview 1.93g David W. Pierce  24 February 2009
>   http://meteora.ucsd.edu:80/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html Copyright (C)
>   1993 through 2009, David W. Pierce Ncview comes with ABSOLUTELY NO
>   WARRANTY; for details type `ncview -w'. This is free software licensed
>   under the Gnu General Public License version 3; type`ncview -c' for
>   redistribution details.
>
> no displayable variables found!

It says `no displayable variables found!`, but via `ncdump -h test.nc`
I am able to see the following lines;

> netcdf test {
>
> // global attributes:
>                   :description = "The data in this file was created for a test" ;
>
> group: grp1 {   dimensions:
>           dim = 30 ;   variables:
>           double data1(dim) ;
>           double data2(dim) ;   } // group grp1
>
> group: grp2 {   dimensions:
>           dim = 30 ;   variables:
>           double data1(dim) ;
>           double data2(dim) ;   } // group grp2 }

Am I missing something in my `Python` script? (I am thinking `ncview` is okay cause I am able to see very same data when I do not save them inside a **netcdf group**)

Comment: Are you certain that ncview is able to deal with variables within netCDF groups? It is a rather old tool and may simply not do that.

Comment: Himm, it might be the problem, but I am using ncview with other netcdf files which have groups, may be I was just lucky. Only difference, they created with Fortran actually, but still all of them NETCDF4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try upgrading your ncview version; 1.93g is pretty old. 2.1.6 (released fall 2015) is available here: http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html

Comment: Thanks @DopplerShift, it is working. The old version I had was supporting the groups as well, but may be python is creating them in a more recent way.